# How do I get to the current picture source of a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

Completely new to coding over here. [Learning the basics.](http://atechkat.blogspot.de/2016/11/005linking-to-new-page.html)

**How can I get to "the picture only", when clicking on a current picture of a slideshow?** 
Normally in *html* I would just put this around it:

```
<a href="image.jpg">Current picture </a>
```

But in this version I just don't seem to get it.
Clicking on the small pictures makes them appear as the big centred one.
Clicking on the big picture currently only pauses/continues the slideshow.

```
$(".crop-img").click(function(){
   $("#bigImage").attr("src",
   $(this).attr("src"));
});

var counter=1;
$("#image"+counter).click();

$("#forward").click(function(){
   counter = counter + 1;
   if (counter>4){
       counter=1;
   }
   $("#image"+counter).click();
})

$("#backward").click(function(){
   counter=counter-1;
   if (counter<1){
       counter=4;
   }
   $("#image"+counter).click();
})

$("#bigImage").click(function(){
   paused=!paused;
})
```

Picture of how it looks is on my [post about it.](http://atechkat.blogspot.de/2016/11/005linking-to-new-page.html)
[image: cliché image gallery]

***Thank you!***

*Full code*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> FWP - Gallery </title>

        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet"
                    type="text/css"
                    href="bootstrap.css">

            <link rel="stylesheet"
                    type="text/css"
                    href="mystyles.css">

            <link rel="stylesheet"
                    type="text/css"
                    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gruppo">

            <link rel="stylesheet"
                    type="text/css"
                    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Syncopate">

    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Image Gallery</h1>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 thin_border">
                <img id="image1"
                    class="crop-img"
                    src="before.jpg"
                    alt="before prisma">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 thin_border">
                <img id="image2"
                    class="crop-img"
                    src="after.jpg"
                    alt="after prisma">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 thin_border">
                <img id="image3"
                    class="crop-img"
                    src="sleepy.jpg"
                    alt="Sleepy cat">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 thin_border">
                <img id="image4"
                    class="crop-img"
                    src="Cute.jpg"
                    alt="Cute cat">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 thin_border">
                <button id="backward">&lt;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 thin_border">
                    <img id="bigImage" 
                        class="big-img"
                        src="before.jpg"
                        alt="before prisma">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 thin_border">
                <button id="forward">&gt;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



        <script>
            var paused=false;

            setInterval(function(){
                if(!paused){
                    $("#forward").click();
                }
            }, 3000);

            $("#bigImage").click(function(){
                    paused=!paused;

                });

            $(".crop-img").click(function(){
                $("#bigImage").attr("src",
                    $(this).attr("src"));
            });
            var counter=1;

            $("#image"+counter).click();

            $("#forward").click(function(){
                counter = counter + 1;
                    if (counter>4) {
                        counter=1;
                    }
                $("#image"+counter).click();
            })

            $("#backward").click(function(){
                counter=counter-1;
                    if (counter<1) {
                        counter=4;
                    }
                    $("#image"+counter).click();
            })

        </script>


    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: How do you want to get the current picture? I mean, what moment in? when you click on a image?

Comment: Also please include the html in the snippet if you want it to work, otherwise you can include a section of code with four indents before each line

Comment: @JoseRojas When clicking on it (the big image), yes. :)

Comment: @jolyeons Not sure what you mean exactly, but I'll add the rest of the code. Thought it would be too much too post.

Comment: @atechkat - if you see in your post there is a 'run snippet' button, this tries to run the code you've provided, so if you want a small runnable snippet that is the way to go.  If you just want to refer to a section of code, which I think is actually what you want, then copy the code into your post but enter four spaces in front of each line, and be sure to have a blank line before it, and the code will stand out but won't give people the impression that this is a runnable section of code

Comment: @jolyeons Aaah! okay, got it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section of javascript isn't vanilla javascript, it is a sample of this 'jquery' that you may have heard of in your quest to learn a bit of coding.

Jquery is syntactic sugar for javascript.  $ is your cue to key in that this might be jquery (there are other js libraries that use $ syntax but I think jquery is the most prevalent).

```
$(".crop-img")
$("#bigImage")
$("#image"+counter)
```

This is jquery code to select an element from the page, the '.' is for selecting class, the '#' is for selecting id, there are tons of others you can look up as well.  This gets you a jquery object that you can then save to a variable, call a method on, etc.

```
$(".crop-img").click(someFunctionNameHere);
$("#image"+counter).click();
```

These are examples of functions being called on the jquery objects, which happen to be event functions.  The first is assigning a function to the click event of the selected element(s) (all elements with class 'crop-img'), the second is firing the click event of the selected element (the element with id='imageX' with 'X' being the current value of counter).

Also instead of a function name, you can just inline the function instead:

```
$("#bigImage").click(function(){
   paused=!paused;
})
```

This assigns the unnamed inline function for the click event of the element with id='bigImage', which is where you want to pull up the image.  Put your code in there that will bring up the image, it will run when the big image is clicked.

Such as if you want to actually go to the image, as in your html example, put this line in there:

```
window.location.href = "someHrefHere";
```

If you want to know the the src of the current bigImage, you can grab it with jquery:

```
var myhref = $("#bigImage").attr("src");
```

You can put it together from there.

Happy Coding!

Comment: If you get stuck, I created a codepen using your full code (and changing image srcs so that it worked for me) http://codepen.io/jolyeons/full/KNdPNY/

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome! The codepen helped a lot!
Didn't now about the window.location.href part. Now I got it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the src of the current image when you click on the big image like this:

```
$( ".row div:nth-child("+counter+") img" ).attr('src')
```

counter was setted as index of your current image and this should be inside of your `$("#bigImage")` click function.